Nfs with Kerberos - Can't connect with sec=krb5*
I can't mount volumes using any sec=krb5*. sec=sys works fine
Machine 1 (M1): nfs-kernel-server/Kerberos [openSUSE] [192.168.2.255] (Yes it's .255 it's a /23 network)
Machine 2 (M2): Client [Debian] [192.168.2.120]
Router (R): DNS/DHCP [OPNSense] [192.168.2.1]

DNS
M1: kerberos.example.org; storage.example.org; nfs.example.org;
M2: intel-deb.example.org
R: opnsense.example.org

Kerberos Principals
host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
host/kerberos.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
host/nfs.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
host/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
nfs/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
nfs/kerberos.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
nfs/nfs.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
nfs/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG

You I've added both nfs/ host/ for each one. But it doesn't it doesn't really metter since gssproxy seems to try any of them man rpc.gssd, but at this point i'm really trying anything
/etc/exports
#/mnt/raid6-main/Users/user intel-deb.example.org(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5p)
/mnt/raid6-main/Users/user  *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,sec=krb5p)

These are some of the configurations on exports that i've been trying
/etc/krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.ORG

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true
        rdns = false


[realms]
    example.org = {
        default_principal_flags = +preauth
        kdc = kerberos.example.org
        admin_server = kerberos.example.org
        default_domain = example.org
        max_life = 12h 0m 0s
        max_renewable_life = 2d 0h 0m 0s
        supported_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 #aes128-cts
        master_key_type = aes256-cts
        acl_file = /mnt/raid6-main/krb5/example.org/etc-krb/kadm5.acl
    }

[domain_realm]
    .example.org = EXAMPLE.ORG
    example.org = EXAMPLE.ORG

[logging]
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/krb5/kadmin.log
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5/krb5lib.log

For M2, I've created a keytab with: ktadd -k /tmp/desktop.keytab host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG then transfered through scp. I can see it is working properly through klist (after kinit -k)
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/29/2024 23:00:35  05/30/2024 11:00:35  krbtgt/example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
    renew until 05/30/2024 23:00:35
05/29/2024 23:00:53  05/30/2024 11:00:35  nfs/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
    renew until 05/30/2024 23:00:35

And for M1 ktadd host/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG and then kinit -k
Ticket cache: DIR::/run/user/0/krb5cc/tktCW9QHa
Default principal: host/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/29/2024 23:06:22  05/30/2024 11:06:22  krbtgt/example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
    renew until 05/30/2024 23:06:22

Both of these, are just for checking. As gssproxy should do this by itself.
For the client, I've read some stuff on gssproxy github, and added some logging. But as far as i can see, everything is okay on the client (M2).
[191225] 1717034889.286347: Retrieving intel-deb$@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for intel-deb$@EXAMPLE.ORG
[191225] 1717034889.286348: Retrieving INTEL-DEB$@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for INTEL-DEB$@EXAMPLE.ORG
[191225] 1717034889.286349: Retrieving root/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for root/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
[191225] 1717034889.286350: Retrieving nfs/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for nfs/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
[191225] 1717034889.286351: Retrieving host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (vno 0, enctype 0) with result: 0/Success
[191225] 1717034889.286352: Retrieving host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG -> Encrypted/Credentials/v1@X-GSSPROXY: from FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 with result: -1765328243/Matching credential not found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_0)
[191225] 1717034889.286353: Getting credentials host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG -> nfs/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG using ccache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_example.org
[191225] 1717034889.286354: Retrieving host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG -> krb5_ccache_conf_data/start_realm@X-CACHECONF: from FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_example.org with result: -1765328243/Matching credential not found (filename: /tmp/krb5ccmachine_example.org)
[191225] 1717034889.286355: Retrieving host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG -> nfs/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG from FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_example.org with result: 0/Success
[191225] 1717034889.286356: Creating authenticator for host/intel-deb.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG -> nfs/storage.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG, seqnum 35569972, subkey aes256-cts/E01D, session key aes256-cts/0264

And on the server side (M1) with this script:
export NFS_RPC_MODULES="nfs nfsd rpc nlm"
for MODULE in $NFS_RPC_MODULES; do
    rpcdebug -m $MODULE -s all
done


I can't see anything usuful as well in /var/log/messages
024-05-29T23:14:27.139096-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308285][T24717] svc: server 0000000035894eaf, pool 0, transport 000000008345429b, inuse=3
2024-05-29T23:14:27.139098-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308588][T24718] svc: server 00000000378add72, pool 0, transport 00000000b5466371, inuse=2
2024-05-29T23:14:27.142908-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308828][T24718] svc: server 00000000378add72, pool 0, transport 00000000b5466371, inuse=2
2024-05-29T23:14:27.142920-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308837][T24718] svc: svc_authenticate (6)
2024-05-29T23:14:27.142922-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308841][T24718] RPC:       Want update, refage=120, age=0
2024-05-29T23:14:27.142924-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.308844][T24718] svc: svc_process close
2024-05-29T23:14:27.181276-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.350921][    C5] RPC:       xs_tcp_state_change client 00000000f11978c9...
2024-05-29T23:14:27.181283-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.350956][    C5] RPC:       state 8 conn 1 dead 0 zapped 1 sk_shutdown 1
2024-05-29T23:14:27.181293-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.350982][    C5] RPC:       xs_data_ready...
2024-05-29T23:14:27.181317-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.350999][T24679] RPC:       xs_close xprt 00000000f11978c9
2024-05-29T23:14:27.182910-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.351030][T24679] RPC:       xs_tcp_state_change client 00000000f11978c9...
2024-05-29T23:14:27.182922-03:00 storage kernel: [17646.351054][T24679] RPC:       state 9 conn 0 dead 0 zapped 1 sk_shutdown 3

And the logs on client after mount -vvv -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p storage.example.org:/mnt/raid6-main/Users/user /mnt/nfs:
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Wed May 29 23:16:26 2024
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.2.255,clientaddr=192.168.2.120'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.2.255,clientaddr=192.168.2.120'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,vers=4,addr=192.168.2.255,clientaddr=192.168.2.120'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting storage.example.org:/mnt/raid6-main/Users/user

Currently showmount -e:
Export list for storage:
/mnt/raid6-main/Users/user *

DNS queries:
;; ANSWER SECTION:
kerberos.example.org. 3600  IN  A   192.168.2.255
;; ANSWER SECTION:
storage.example.org.    3600    IN  A   192.168.2.255
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nfs.example.org.    3600    IN  A   192.168.2.255
;; ANSWER SECTION:
intel-deb.example.org. 3600 IN  A   192.168.2.120

Reverse queries:
;; ANSWER SECTION:
120.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR intel-deb.example.org
;; ANSWER SECTION:
255.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR nfs.example.org.
255.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR storage.example.org.
255.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN PTR kerberos.example.org.

On M1 there are entries on /etc/hosts for:
127.0.0.1 kerberos.example.org
127.0.0.1 storage.example.org
127.0.0.1 nfs.example.org


I can't brain today, but just for checking: 0) Are you really using a lower-case realm name? 1) Does the client's rpc.gssd cache, klist -c /tmp/krb5ccmachine_REALM, have a krbtgt ticket? 2) Does the client's rpc.gssd successfully get a nfs/your.server ticket (in the same cache) when a mount is attempted?


Are those server principals set up as aliases of each other on the KDC, or are they completely independent (with distinct keys)? 4) Could you switch those DNS entries to CNAMEs instead of direct A records? That would help Kerberos a little, as it could then canonicalize to a single server principal name (and therefore to a single keytab entry).


[That all being said, this is really not a StackOverflow question – it's a programming Q&A site – and would be better on ServerFault or SU...]

Nope, the realm name should be EXAMPLE.ORG . My bad, it changed the string on the sed. I'm gonna try later the CNAME. It's kinda funny because i was able to make it run with nfs-ganesha but not with nfs-kernel-server


They are distinct keys, I've tried removing the other A records, and use only storage.example.org aswell

